# Generating PDF from qwebview does not include images

Tags: qt

I m creating pdf file from QWebView.

```
class myView: public QWebView
{
}
```

One of the member function has:

```
 this->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrintElementBackgrounds, true);
 QPrinter printer;
 printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
 printer.setResolution(QPrinter::HighResolution);
 printer.setOutputFileName("whoami.pdf");
 print(&printer);
```

I see the  pdf file is generated, but the html file has few images which are not
coming in the pdf, it is blank.

Surfing the net did not help much, and i also enabled WebSetting like:

```
 this->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrintElementBackgrounds, true);
```

Could someone kindly suggest what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should first say to the print to wait in tell the page finish loading so you should

1. add this to your code :

   ```
   connect(&document, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(printpdf()));
   ```

where document is your qwebview variable;

2. then you creat your private slot :

   ```
   printpdf();
   ```

in this function you should call the printer and print(&printer);

**don't forget**,
in your html the  in scr you should add file:///

exemple

```
<img src="file:///c:/image.jpg" />
```